# Is it possible to disable the text input in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

Is it possible to disable the text input including the send button completely for the react-native-gifted-chat component?

This is my current component:

`<GiftedChat text={emergencyText} onInputTextChanged={this.setEmergencyText} />`

I could override the render methods, but how do I then render the original input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since React-native-gifted-chat does not have the disable props for it provides one more component, that is `InputToolbar`, if we render null value to we can almost disable the sending feature. just try the below code.

```
  <InputToolbar
    render={null}
    text={emergencyText} 
    onInputTextChanged={this.setEmergencyText}
  />
```

It serves your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  disableComposer prop.

```
<GiftedChat disableComposer={true}  text={emergencyText} onInputTextChanged={this.setEmergencyText} />
```